# Cannot read property 'value' of undefined - mongoose 5.6.0

Tags: mongoose

When using mongoose's findOne function and searching by a specific field, I am encountering a strange error.  I am using mongoose 5.6.0 and mongoDB 3.6.9.

I cannot figure out what the problem is, please help!

Here is the call:

```
User.findOne({googleId:googleId})
    .select('-password')
    .exec()
    .then(user => {
        if(user)
        {
            const googleUser = user;
            return done(null, googleUser);
        }
        else
        {
            const newUser = new User({
                _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                method: "Google",
                email: profile.emails[0].value,
                googleId: googleId,
                role: "User"
            });

            newUser.save()
            .then(saveduser => {
                const googleUser = saveduser;
                return done(null, googleUser);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                log.error("Error saving Google ID: " + googleId + " => " + error.message);
                return done(error, false)
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        log.error("Error looking up Google ID: " + googleId + " => " + error.message);
        return done(error, false)
    })
```

Here is the User Schema:

```
/*
==============================================
User Model
==============================================
*/

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    email: { 
        type: String,         
        unique: true,
    },
    password: { 
        type: String,
        required: function() {
            return this.method === "Local";
        }
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Developer", "Admin", "Moderator", "User"],
        required: true
    },
    enabled: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: true
    },
    method: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Local", "Google", "Facebook"],
        default: "Local"
    },
    googleId: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    },
    facebookId: {
        type: String,
        default: ''
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

And here is the error:

[2019-06-14T22:47:16.055] Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `profile` which either does not have the `emails` array or the array is empty since `profile.emails[0].value` is where you get the error.

Just check to make sure that you have the emails array and there is a  first element.

You could do something like this:

```
email: profile && profile.emails && profile.emails.length && profile.emails[0].value
```

or even better just pass that email to this section and sanitize it beforehand.

Comment: Wow.  What a catch.  I went down the complete wrong rabbit hole on that one.  Cheers :D

Comment: Just confirmed.  Missing the scope from my google auth.  Pulled an older commit where I seemed to have delete it.  Thanks again!